# Remove item from JSON returned from API

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and have some trouble trying to delete an item from some data returned by an API

```php
function getData()
{    
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',));
    

    $data = curl_exec($ch);


    echo $data;
    exit();
}
```

Here is the JSON data, I want to remove the item with `Id 11`, how can I do this?

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Id": 11,
            "Name": "Name1"
        },
        {
            "Id": 12,
            "Name": "Name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode), [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach), [`if`](http://php.net/if), [`unset`](http://php.net/unset), [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Decode the data.
2. Remove the item from the array.
3. Optionally encode it again as string if needed.

```php
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($dataArray['Data'] as $key => $item) {
    if ($item['Id'] === 11) {
        unset($dataArray['Data'][$key]);
    }
}

$data = json_encode($dataArray);
```

Comment: the ```foreach``` loop can be replaced with ```$dataArray=array_filter($dataArray,function($el){return $el["Id"]<>11;});```

Comment: @ИгорьТыра That's an answer not a comment.  Post it.

Comment: nevermind this worked perfectly, I have different names on my actual code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have in mind, while the `array_filter` might be more fancy, it's slower than the foreach :)

Comment: @ИгорьТыра this actually didn't work though, undefined index Id, i think the stepp missing is cause Id is inside an object

Answer (score 2):

it will work

```
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
$dataArray['Data'] = array_filter($dataArray['Data'], function($el){return $el["Id"]<>11;});
$data = json_encode($dataArray);
```

Comment: Have in mind, while the `array_filter` might be more fancy, it's slower than the foreach :)

Comment: ok your example works but need use the property name  `$dataArray["Data"]`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to re-index by `Id` and `unset` it:

```
$array = array_column(json_decode($data, true)['Data'], null, 'Id'));
unset($array[11]);
```

Now `$array` is indexed by `Id`.  If you want to reset it, then:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```